# Scheduling operations with Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to postpone an event using Kivy. More specifically, I want to present a text label on screen, and then delete it after ***N*** seconds. 
So far I understand that `time.sleep` won't do the job. Instead, I try to create a separate function (called `eraser()`) that deletes whatever is on the screen, then to call it using `Clock.schedule_once(eraser, n)`.

This is what I have so far:

```
class myLayout(FloatLayout):
    def eraser(self):
        self.canvas.clear()

    def _keyboard_on_key_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        self.canvas.clear()

        global i
        i = i + 1
        initialy = 400-(stim_list[i]/2)
        xlab = Label(text='X', pos=(0, 350))

        with self.canvas:
            self.add_widget(xlab)
            Color(1., 1, 1)
            Rectangle(pos=(initialx, initialy), size=(stimwidth, stim_list[i]))

        Clock.schedule_once(eraser(),3)
```

That's not really working, I would appreciate if anyone can think of the right/better way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Widget` and `Canvas` are completely different things, therefore cleaning only the canvas obviously won't remove the widget itself and in the end with this technique the `FloatLayout` will have **a lot** of `Label` widgets as children without actually removing them - call it a leak if you want :)

Widget uses [`add_widget()`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.add_widget), [`remove_widget()`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.remove_widget) and [`clear_widgets()`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.clear_widgets) calls and each of them is **out** of the `with <canvas>` block, though yes, it works even that way if you actually need it to behave like that.

[`Clock.schedule_once()`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.CyClockBase.schedule_once) call on the other hand uses the function/method you pass to it, which in your case is just a returning value of `eraser()` (which is `None`) and executes the function at the same place where you wrote it with the brackets (`eraser()` → call, `eraser` → just a function).

Therefore:

- use `add_widget()`, `remove_widget()` and `clear_widgets()`

  - don't place them into `with <canvas>` block unless necessary (mostly isn't!)
- pass the function/method as an argument, not their returned values (don't use brackets)

Example:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_string('''
<Test>:
    Button:
        size_hint: None, None
        on_release: root.test()
''')


class Test(FloatLayout):
    def eraser(self, *args):
        self.clear_widgets()

    def test(self, *args):
        lab = Label(text='Hello world!')
        self.add_widget(lab)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.eraser, 3)


runTouchApp(Test())
```